# SVN Checkout without Commit Ability

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there anyway to checkout or export a directory in SVN or TortoiseSVN onto a local machine and have the ability to update, but not commit to that directory?

Basically, I want to export a directory, but still be able to easily update it using something like TortoiseSVN.  I could simply reexport the directory, but I'd like to have a more simple way of updating the files.

**EXAMPLE**:

I have a script that is run daily and resides in a specific directory on my system.  I want to be able to easily update that script to the latest revision in SVN.  I could accomplish this by checking out a copy of the script from SVN, but this does allow someone to commit any changes made to it back into the repo.

Instead, all changes made to the script are done elsewhere in a development directory (thus allowing the no changes to the script to be made during development).  When significant progress has been made to the script I'd like to simply navigate to it and perform an update to get the latest (or a specific revision), so is there anyway I can get a working copy of a directory / file in SVN that doesn't allow commits to originate from it, but from other working copies?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you get any errors? I see no reason, why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, but obviously, allowing or disallowing commits is a setting on the _server_, not on the client. Just create a user without write permissions.

Comment: I don't want to disallow commits on the server, just coming from this one particular "working copy".

I want the ability to update a directory to the latest revision, but not to be able to commit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via shell or batch scripts. First export all the files from svn to your machine. Find out the revision which was exported, say 1050. Create a text file,revision.txt with content 1050.

Now use the below shell script.

[image]

This will find out the difference from `revision_from` to `revision_to` and will export the changes from SVN. The above script will not deal with deleted files. You can do that also by adding one more if condition, something like the below:

[image]

Once the current export is done, it will update the file revision.txt with the latest revision from svn, for the next run.